# How can i add rows in an UItableView with data contained in a NSDictionnary?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I want manage a chat with messages (as native iphone application) where in a first time only ten messages are displayed. Then, i want to be able to load and displayed ten others messages in the UItableview.I've found a method to add object in an array and after in the tableView :

```
-(IBAction)addCity:(id)sender
{
    [dataArray addObject:@"City"];
    NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[dataArray count]-1 inSection:1]];
    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

But my data are contained in a NSDictionnary (avatar, message, name).
Can i use the same method with a NSDictionnary ? How ?
Is there an other way ?

Thanks everyone for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that when you're asked to provide cell information, you have to be able to find it using two numbers: one number that matches a section in your table and another that matches a row within that section.  Dictionaries aren't very good at finding things by number; arrays are.

From what you've written, it sounds as if each message is in a dictionary.  That suggests that -- assuming your table only has one section -- you need an array of dictionaries so that a dictionary can be found by row number and then the message portion put into a table cell.

Comment: in fact I think it is a good solution. I try it. Thanks you !